# Unable to show Admob Native Ad in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, admob

I am trying to show admob native ad using the xml format and AndroidViewBinding in jetpack compose. Ad does not show at all and but I do not get any useful error message.

Inside `onAdFailedToLoad` I just get "Internal error." exception.

And for XML itself, when I validate the file I get "Error:(5, 42) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView'." .

I enabled viewBinding inside build.gradle file. All necessary dependencies have been added.

This is composable function:

```
@Composable
fun NativeAdView(adUnitId: String) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 200.dp)) {
        AndroidViewBinding(
            factory = { inflater, parent, attachToParent ->
                val binding = NativeAdViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, attachToParent)
                val adView = binding.root.also { adView ->
                    adView.headlineView = binding.adHeadline
                    adView.iconView = binding.adAppIcon
                }
                try {
                    val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(
                        adView.context,
                        adUnitId,
                    )
                        .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                            nativeAd.icon?.let {
                                binding.adAppIcon.setImageDrawable(it.drawable)
                                binding.adAppIcon.isVisible = true
                            }
                            nativeAd.headline?.let {
                                if (it.isNotBlank()) {
                                    binding.adHeadline.text = it
                                    binding.adHeadline.isVisible = true
                                }
                            }

                            adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                        }
                        .withAdListener(
                            object : AdListener() {
                                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
                                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(error)

                                }
                            },
                        )
                        .withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder().build())
                        .build()
                    adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("Exception", e.message.toString())
                }
                binding
            },
        )
    }
}
```

This is UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test ad" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="ad_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few minutes ago i was solving same issue. I am still in development, didn't tested it in production, but i was able to load native ads. For me this worked:

**1. Make sure you added metadata APPLICATION_ID**

```
    <manifest>
      <application>
      <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
          android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
          ...

      </application>
    </manifest>
```

**2. Make sure ads sdk is initialized before loading any ad**

```
   MobileAds.initialize(context) {
        //Now you can load ad
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }
```

**3. Use "/6499/example/native" adUnitId**

Now i can't really explain why but for debugging it's working with this ad unit id "**/6499/example/native**". I found it in this [example project](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/kotlin/admanager/NativeAdsExample), it contains working implementation how to load and display native ad.

Comment: Thank you very much. Step 3. was solution. I used ad unit ID which is provided in their documentation. I didn't think that could be the reason why it's not showing...